# Calculated Columns - IF statement to find all numbers inbetween a selected area

Tags: list, column, string

Since my title is unclear let me explain.

I'm currently trying to work out if I can use an IF statement to find numbers inbetween a selected amount.

Example:

```
=IF([Weeks Left]="1-12","coming soon",IF([Weeks Left]="13-26","Plenty time left"))
```

Something along those lines...

I know that I can't use 1-12, but I would rather not use an if for 1, 2, 3, 4 etc. As the column I had in mind would basically need to have ifs for 52 weeks to 400.

Is there a statement to include if the number equals 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11 or 12 that It'll display "Coming Soon" in one line?

Cheers

Comment: Have you tried the lower than operator ? "<12"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use greater than lesser than condition

```
IF(AND([Weeks Left]>=1,[Weeks Left]<=12),"coming soon",IF(AND([Weeks Left]>=13,[Weeks Left]<=26),"Plenty time left","None"))
```

Comment: Just the answer I was looking for, thanks very much sir

Comment: please mark it as an answer if it resolves your problem

Comment: Upon using this code it doesn't seem to work, although I don't spot a syntax anywhere?

Comment: please try the edited formula. i missed second parameter for IF loop.